# How can f System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, t-sql, windows-services

I have a windows service that call a Web Service, then stored the information in my t-sql database. In my pc this service works, but in another pc with the same database I have this error:

```
[16:06:00] Teresa Gabriele: Errore saveLocalActivity:    in System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   in System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   in System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   in GestoreService.Manager.Impl.AttivitaManagerImpl.saveLocalActivity(LOCAL_PE_Attivita attivita, Boolean saving) in c:\Users\michele.castriotta\Source\Workspaces\Omniacare\software\exercise platform\GestoreService\GestoreService\Manager\Impl\AttivitaManagerImpl.cs:riga 25
[16:06:52] Teresa Gabriele: Errore isAttivitaXMedicoExist:    in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TInterceptionContext,TResult](Func`1 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`1 executing, Action`1 executed)
   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   in System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   in System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass57.<ExecuteStoreCommand>b__56()
   in System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   in System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass57.<ExecuteStoreCommand>b__55()
   in System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   in System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior, String commandText, Object[] parameters)
   in System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior, String sql, Object[] parameters)
   in System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior, String sql, Object[] parameters)
   in System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(String sql, Object[] parameters)
   in GestoreService.Manager.Impl.AttivitaManagerImpl.inserAttivitaXMedico(Int32 idAttivita, String codiceFiscaleOperatoreMedico, String username) in c:\Users\michele.castriotta\Source\Workspaces\Omniacare\software\exercise platform\GestoreService\GestoreService\Manager\Impl\AttivitaManagerImpl.cs:riga 192
```

This is the code:

```
 _db.LOCAL_PE_Attivita.Add(attivita);
int result = _db.SaveChanges(); //LINE 25
if (result > 0)
return true;
```

Comment: The Question isn't clear. Anyway, I think that error is in Save on DB and not related to the windows service (or application). So i see that you use EF and if on your pc this code work, we can assume that error is not EF but eventually in SQLCommand. From my point of view I think that there is a difference in DB version. Are you sure that there is same version of DB on both PCs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Question is unclear, but I think that error is not in the code. 
The log tell that error is in save on DB, but if this application work only on your pc I think (probably) that related to different version of DB.

checks whether this is the problem

Comment: the problem is n the two table, because they are not updated